# Pasting from Excel into Outlook using objWord.Selection Error 91: Object variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I have code that creates an appointment in Outlook and pastes a range of cells.

The code fails the first time but then works on the second time. I click on End when the error pops up and then run the macro again and it works.

> Run-time error '91':
> Object variable or With block variable not set

At `objSel.PasteAndFormat (wdChartPicture)`

Full code:

```vb
Sub Meeting_InvitesNEW()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set ObjMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim Mymail As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Call GetData
'Set the range
Set testRange = Range("$A$10:$AD$500")
'Get the cell or range that the user selected
Set myRange = Selection
'Check if the selection is inside the range.
If Intersect(testRange, myRange) Is Nothing Then
    'Selection is NOT inside the range.
    MsgBox "You are not on a loan", vbCritical, "Read me"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Worksheets("Manager County Info").Range("14:18").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Manager County Info").Range("D7:I18").Copy

    Set Mymail = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    Mymail.Display

    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")) 'wait 5 seconds from now

    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objSel As Word.Selection

    Set objItem = Mymail
    Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector
    Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
    Set objWord = objDoc.Application

    With Mymail
        .RequiredAttendees = Worksheets("Loans").Range("k" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        .Subject = Worksheets("Loans").Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " (LGI Builder LO - " & Worksheets("Loans").Range("K" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & ")" _
           & " COE " & Worksheets("Loans").Range("W" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " (" & Worksheets("Loans").Range("Q" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & ")"
        ' .Location = "Borrower Cell"
        .Start = Worksheets("Loans").Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " " & 
        Format(Worksheets("Loans").Range("O" & ActiveCell.Row).Value, "h:mm")
        .Duration = 90
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 180
        .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
    
        If Worksheets("Loans").Range("K" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "Mario Cerrato" Then
            .BusyStatus = olBusy
        Else
            .BusyStatus = olFree
        End If
    End With

    '    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")) 'wait 5 seconds from now

    Set objSel = objWord.Selection
    objSel.PasteAndFormat (wdChartPicture)
    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objInsp = Nothing
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Set objSel = Nothing
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set Mymail = Nothing
    Set exclapp = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End If
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This can be if your selection not coerced to the type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not quite sure what you mean? I am copying a range from another sheet (Manager County Info) in the same excel file, here is the code excerpt:
Worksheets("Manager County Info").Range("D7:I18").Copy

Comment: Before ` With Mymail` insert this line Debug.Print  objDoc , objWord . You have to get the word document name and the application name. In this case the Excel cells are inserted for me.